# Is it better to do authorization in a view or controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

(View)

```
//deny access to these Roles Beside Admin(Role3)
if (RoleId == 1 || RoleId == 2 || RoleId == 4)
{
//Redirect to home if RoldId is not 3
    Response.Redirect("~/Home/Index");
}
```

or

(Controller)

```
//deny other Roles Beside Admin
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public ActionResult AdminOnly()
{
return View();
}
```

both work the same but which is better and why?

Comment: The second approach is the standard one.

Comment: Suppose you get a new role in future. Then this role would with approach 1 automatically get admin access. In such cases whitelists are always better than blacklists, hence do approach 2.

Comment: where do you get `role id` from?

Comment: @oldbam its from my own Custom Role Table

Comment: Controllers should control and views should format output. So method 2 is more in keeping with that philosophy. Plus, method 1 uses "magic numbers", which is always bad juju. What does `RoleId==1` *even mean* (to the next poor dev that has to maintain this).

Comment: In addition to what was said, doing it in the view might become a security issue if your controller does something like executing a database modification (create, update, delete) - as the controller gets executed before the view checks the permission unauthorized users might be able to perform database transactions they are not supposed to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your view is rendered by Razor View Engine to HTML code in the server side you may notice no difference. To be particular, the major difference between the two approaches is that the first one is not safe in cases where there is a chance for an error to occur or an exception to be thrown and this results in ugly error pages and inefficient exception handling.

This is while the latter approach can be considered as the best since it allows you to handle all exceptions or errors in the controller, or more importantly you can render your returned view based on the role of the user.

For example:

```
[CustomAuthorize] 
public IActionResult AdminDashboard(){
     if(HttpContext.User.IsInRole("Admin"))
         return View("X");
     else if (HttpContext.User.IsInRole("Guest"))
         return View("Y");
     else 
        return RedirectToAction("Some Action");
        // Or throw an exception 
}
```

And furthermore, you can write an exception handling attribute to handle the exception thrown at controller level or when rendering the result. This can be done through inhering from `Attribute` and implementing `IActionFilter` and `IResultFilter` interfaces.

For example:

```
public class HandleLoginAttribute : Attribute, IActionFilter, IResultFilter
{
    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        if (context.Exception != null) {
            // Handle exceptions thrown by the action api
        }
    }

    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {

    }

    public void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext context)
    {
        if (context.Exception != null)
        {
            // Handle exceptions thrown when rendering the view
        }
    }

    public void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext context)
    {

    }
}
```

So you can have something like:

```
[HandleLogin]
[CustomAuthorize] 
public IActionResult AdminDashboard(){
     if(HttpContext.User.IsInRole("Admin"))
         return View("X");
     else if (HttpContext.User.IsInRole("Guest"))
         return View("Y");
     else 
        return RedirectToAction("Some Action");
}
```

And the key advantage is that you can reuse all these effectively while you cannot do (or you cannot effectively do) inside views.

Answer (score 1):

Controller if its a role based one.
Though views can still use some convention if there're further granular need for distribution.

eg. Both receptionists and doctors can have access to same patient details, but using view based authorization you can then probably granularly distribute what fields are available to what role for either view or edit.